# Update multiple columns in one table based on values in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a tableA, that holds 40 million records. It has this structure

```
Id A B C
1 N O 10
1 N O 20
2 B G 15
2 B G 25
3 E U 50
3 E U 60
```

I need to change the values in column A and B in tableA based on values in tableB (where id is unique). Table B looks like this

```
Id A B
1 V M
2 Q W
3 E U
```

Thus ending up with the result for table A

```
Id A B C
1 V M 10
1 V M 20
2 Q W 15
2 Q W 25
3 E U 50
3 E U 60
```

Since Id=3 is the same in both table A and B I would rather avoid to write from B to A for those records, thinking that would be more efficient?

I thought along these lines

```
UPDATE tableA
SET A = (SELECT A
         FROM tableB
         WHERE tabelA.id = tableB.id)
```

But not sure when I need to update several columns in the same step, and also in terms of only update if data really is different between tableA and tableB.

Comment: benka, sorry I messed up those tables. Thanks for editing. How do you make tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables:

```
UPDATE tableA JOIN tableB USING (Id)
SET    tableA.A = tableB.A,
       tableA.B = tableB.B
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df97e/1/0).

Comment: `USING (Id)` can be replaced with `ON tableA.Id = tableB.Id`

Comment: I don't try to correct you. Just left this information for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update A a
inner join B b on a.id = b.id
set a.A = b.A, 
    a.B = b.B
WHERE a.A <> b.A and a.B <> b.B
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query for this but you have to put your **where condition** as you want.

```
UPDATE tabe2
SET subject_id = (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sub_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS sub_id
        FROM tabe1
        )
```