# MySQL ... Update One Table w/ Values from Another; Multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to update table2 w/ the xnum values from table1 where item and date from table1 are equal to item and date from table2.

```
table1: id,item,sdate,xnum (id is primary key, features additional columns, identical to table2)
         1,G,2021-01-01,201
         2,G,2021-02-01,202
         3,G,2021-03-01,203
         4,B,2021-04-01,204
         5,B,2021-05-01,205
         6,B,2021-06-01,206
         7,B,2021-07-01,207
         8,C,2021-08-01,208
         9,C,2021-09-01,209

table2: id,item,sdate,xnum (id is primary key, features additional columns, identical to table1)
         1,G,2021-01-01,000
         2,G,2021-03-01,000
         3,B,2021-05-01,000
         4,B,2021-07-01,000
         5,C,2021-09-01,000
```

I'm seeking this as the result:

```
table2: id,item,sdate,xnum
         1,G,2021-01-01,201
         2,G,2021-03-01,203
         3,B,2021-05-01,205
         4,B,2021-07-01,207
         5,C,2021-09-01,209
```

I've attempted to adapt the results here [Update multiple columns in one table based on values in another table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261022/update-multiple-columns-in-one-table-based-on-values-in-another-table-in-mysql) to my needs, but the query has not completed / takes too long to complete. There are about 150K rows in each table.

```
UPDATE
  table2
  JOIN table1 USING (item, sdate)
SET
  table2.xnum = table1.xnum;
```

So, I'm still wondering how to *efficiently* update the xnum column values in table2 with the xnum column values in table1, w/ the condition that two fields (item and sdate) match.

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. If it's slow, add appropriate indexes to both tables.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX (item, sdate);` and the same for `table2`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar ... That did it!